# Minimum Permission to Restart SQL Services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent

Occasionally, our developers need to restart SQL services.  We do not want said developers to be local admins on each server if not necessary.  What is the minimum permission required so that the developers can restart the SQL Services (database engine and agent) remotely using SSMS?  We use SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  grant the Service Start/Stop right for the SQL Server and Agent service to the Developers or their Windows group.

You can use

- Use Group Policy
- Security Templates or
- Use Subinacl.exe

Above all are described in this KB article [How to grant users rights to manage services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325349)

As a side note, you can use sysinternals tool - [accesschk.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx). It will help you to find out -

> what kind of accesses specific users or groups have to resources including files, directories, Registry keys, global objects and Windows services.

Comment: Will the steps work the same for Server 2008?

Comment: Yes, it will work. check [Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx)- The process is similar on other versions of Windows.